# Redirect requests to CloudFront based on header (for crawlers)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

I'm serving a React app from CloudFront, and I need to be able to redirect requests coming from crawlers (identified via a `user-agent` header) to a static version of the site.

It looks like lambda@edge would fit my needs (I could inspect the headers in a Lambda function, then redirect if necessary) but it's in a limited preview and I've been unable to get access.

How else can I achieve this?